# Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry for: client of type: com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient

Tags: spring-boot, azure, apache-camel, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to connect to my Azure blob container and upload the file as soon as a new file is created in a directory. I have created a blob client and added URL and credentials into the camel registry. But, I'm getting no bean created issue. Can someone help me with this?

```java
@Component
public class CamelConfig extends RouteBuilder {

  StorageSharedKeyCredential credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(
      "accName",
      "accesskey"
  );

  String uri = String.format("https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net","accName");

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    try {
      CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
      SftpWatcherRoute route = new SftpWatcherRoute();
      BlobServiceClient client = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
          .endpoint(uri)
          .credential(credential)
          .buildClient();
      context.getRegistry().bind("client", client);
      route.addRoutesToCamelContext(context);
      context.start();
      Thread.sleep(5000);
      context.stop();

    } catch (Exception exe) {
      exe.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

```java
@Service
public class SftpWatcherRoute extends RouteBuilder {
  @Override
  public void configure() {
    from("file-watch:hello?events=CREATE&antInclude=**/*.txt&recursive=true")
        .routeId("fileWatch")
        .to("direct:uploadFileToBlob")
        .end();

    from("direct:uploadFileToBlob")
        .routeId("uploadFile")
        .to("azure-storage-blob://accName/containerName?blobName=test.txt&serviceClient=#client")
        .end();
  }
}
```

**Exception:**

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry for: client of type: com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient
    at org.apache.camel.support.CamelContextHelper.mandatoryLookupAndConvert(CamelContextHelper.java:253) ~[camel-support-3.14.0.jar:3.14.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that `SftpWatcherRoute.configure` gets called before `CamelConfig.configure` or that the latter doesn't get called at all. Using RouteBuilder to configure CamelContext is generally a bad idea if multiple RouteBuilders depend upon said configurations.

For most cases you're better off configuring CamelContext (including adding beans to registry) using [CamelContextConfiguration](https://camel.apache.org/camel-spring-boot/latest/spring-boot.html#_custom_camel_context_configuration) or just configuring the context when service gets [created](https://camel.apache.org/camel-spring-boot/latest/spring-boot.html#_auto_configured_camel_context).